# annotate command "no such load to file" with -R

Tags: ruby, annotate

The `annotate` command fails when using the `-R` option to load additional files before loading the models with version 2.4.1.beta. The files appear to be found, but the error still occurs (if I use a wild-card path the first file is displayed as the error). A similar error message appears here (https://github.com/ctran/annotate_models/issues/78) The solution there is to use:

`gem 'annotate', github: 'ctran/annotate_models'`

but if I replace `annotate` in the `Gemfile` with the above, and do:

```
gem uninstall annotate
bundle install
```

Then `bundle` reports on the first line:
Updating git://github.com/ctran/annotate_models.git

and later:
Using annotate (2.5.0.pre1) from git://github.com/ctran/annotate_models.git (at master)

Note that neither message says "Installing". Then executing `annotate` ends up with the annotate executable not being found. Any solutions? (Ruby 1.9.2p280, Rails 3.2.2)

Comment: what?! if you uninstall the gem, you are not able to execute the binary? i think this is an expected behavior, isn't it?

Comment: Sorry. See new text. bundle install should reinstall the new gem, so why isn't it installed/found?